# Angular 2/4 -- When binding a radio button [value] to an object or function, why does this reactive form value not update?

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

*NOTE: if anyone has a better way of doing this, I'm all ears.

I'm attempting to create a form with three radio buttons -- two with a static value, and one with a custom, user-generated value. Here's what's happening:

I have the default set to one:
[image: default set to one]

When I click two, everything works as expected:

[image: when I click two]

When I click the custom radio button, everything works as expected:

[image: when I click three]

When I enter a value, the object correctly gets mutated, but the form value (which is set to one of the objects keys) doesn't update:

[image: form value doesn't update when I enter a value in input]

I can click back to two and get expected behavior:

[image: when I click back to two I see expected behavior]

And when I then click back to three, I see expected behavior:

[image: when I click back to three, I see expected behavior]

Here's my code:

**test.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <label for="every_fifteen_minutes">
        <input id="two" type="radio" formControlName="test" value="one">
        <span class="input_text">This [value] will always be one</span>
    </label>
    <label for="two">
        <input id="two" type="radio" formControlName="test" value="two">
        <span class="input_text">This [value] will always be two</span>
    </label>
    <label for="three">
        <input id="three" type="radio" formControlName="test" [(value)]="myObj.strKey">
        <span>This [value] should be set to the input value:</span>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObj.strKey" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </label>
</form>
<div>this.myObj.str: {{getThat()}}</div>
<div>this: {{getThis()}}</div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
myForm: any;
myObj: any = {
    strKey: ""
}

private _buildForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        'test': ['1', Validators.required],
    })
}

ngOnInit() { 
    this._buildForm();
}

getThat(): number {
    return this.myForm.get('test').value
}

getThis(): string {
    return this.myObj.strKey;
}
```

---

SO, my question is: why is the update not happening immediately, how can I get it to happen, and is it possible to do this in a less complicated way?

Answer (score 0):

try add (input)="0" in

```
<input id="three" type="radio" formControlName="test" [(value)]="myObj.strKey">
```

like this

```
<input id="three" type="radio" formControlName="test" [(value)]="myObj.strKey" (input)="0">
```

Comment: Do you have the documentation for this? I tried it and it didn't work for me, but I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your question. I think that the value of formControl will set only one time when it to be selected ,that’s why the value of the input of id “three” had changed but the value of the formControl didn’t